# Combinatorics: How many subsets of size k are there in a group of N elements?

Tags: combinatorics

***Updating the question after some comments.***

If I have a multiset consisting of elements {1, 1, 2, 2, 3}. How can I mathematically find the number of distinct sub-multisets with size 2?

The answer for that happens to be 5 with the following subsets: (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 2), (2, 3)

Repetition: I think this small python snippet will explain the rules for repetitions in the subset.

```
numbers = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3]
s = set()
s.add(tuple())
for L in range(0, len(numbers) + 1):
    for comb in itertools.combinations(numbers, L):
        s.add(sorted(comb))
```

The reason I am using a set **s** is to avoid duplicates.

```
for comb in itertools.combinations(numbers, 2):
    print comb
```

This will generate the following result.

(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 2), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 3)

I hope the question is clear now.

Comment: A set can't contain repeated elements: $\{1, 1, 2, 2, 3\} = \{1, 2, 3\}$.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese He's working with multi sets.

Comment: @CalvinLin: That may be worth mentioning in the question.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Agreed, and he also needs to explain the conditions better, since the answer depends heavily on the number of repeats.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese, I have updated the question. I hope it is clear now.

Comment: @KrishnaBharadwaj: Much better, thanks.

Comment: You’re not looking for either the number of subsets or the number of sub-multisets; you seem to be looking for the number of distinct sub-multisets.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, thanks for the correction. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that the multiset has $a$ elements which occur exactly once and $b$ elements which occur more than once.  Then there are:

- $\binom{a+b}{2}$ multisets of the form $\{x,y\}$ with $x \neq y$, and
- $b$ multisets of the form $\{x,x\}$.

So there are $\binom{a+b}{2}+b$ distinct sub-multisets.